# Don't why the colours aren't changing in this CSS file

Tags: css

I am doing a Ruby and rails project and wanted to do some styling in CSS.  The problem is the colours aren't changing. Here is my code.

```
div.alert {
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.flash.success {
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: green;
}

div.flash.error   {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
}

div.flash.notice  {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body> <% flash.each do |type, message| %>  
   <div class="alert flash <%= type %>"> <%= message %> </div> <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
 </body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The above code is in my application css

Comment: Please show more information: the HTML of what is not changing. From your CSS you're using different classes

Comment: where is your rendered HTML?

Comment: Please add your HTML as rendered in the browser (right click and "view source" in the browser). Either the css file isn't being added to the page, or the `<%= type %>` isn't outputting the right value to match a class, or there is another syntax error in the CSS file that is breaking it, but we can't tell exactly what it is without the actual output HTML.